# Facebook Post from Server Side Code - How to I get Working Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

After spending hours searching and reading through many posts and the Facebook docs, I have not been able to successfully post to Facebook from my Server Application.  Hope someone can help.

Scenario: From within my worker thread running in the cloud, when someone performs and action in my web based application I want to post to my companies Facebook application.  “A new “blank” is now available… “.

To get an access token from the server side code I’ve use any of the following and I do get what appears to be an access token:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=&client_secret=&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=&client_secret=&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages

When I attempt to use the access token to post I get a 403 Forbidden Access.

Then I used the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  Selected my Facebook Application, clicked on “Get Access Token”, I was prompted with a dialog to grant permissions which “publish_stream, manage_pages, offline_access”.  Got the access token, which was much longer, temporarily put it in my code and IT WORKED.  I could post to my company app from my server side code.

Yes, I know that “offline access” is deprecated.  It was weird through that it was still available in the Graph API Explorer.

Since this is my company Facebook site, I’d like to post to it programmatically without prompting a user for permissions.  Twitter enables this scenario.

Any pointers?  At a loss now.  Using c#.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding 1) Why are you using the deprecated offline_access permission when it's not supported 2) Whether this is an app page or a regular page 3) Why you are not using the page token 4) What's the actual api call you are using 5) Why something that works for Twitter running OAuth 1.0 would work for Facebook running OAuth 2.0 6) you are most likely doing something pretty wonky to get an HTTP 403 instead of an actual API error.

Comment: 1. I'd prefer not to use the offline_access permission of course.  Can you provide a recommended solution?  That's waht I am asking for.  It's strange that it's still surfaced through the Graph APIExplorer.

Comment: 2.  This is an App page.

Comment: 3. I'm not familar with the Page token
4. The actual API that I am using to get the token is described above, I am using https://graph.facebook.com/<page id>/feed?... for posting.
5. I am not using the Twitter solution.  I was just pointing out that the scnario is supported on Twitter.
6. The 403 is a result of the Token that I get from the code above, when I get the token from the Graph API Explorer the "wonky" code as you say works fine.

Comment: It works in the explorer because the call is correct there. If you inspect the HTTP 403 with a proper HTTP logging tool (for example some devs use Fiddler) to see the full response there should be the Graph API error as well, if there isn't then as I said it's weird/wonky.

Comment: Is the "server side" scenario supported and do you have any suggestions on where to look to find a solution without the "offline_access" permission?  Because I did check off the "offline_access" permissions in the explorer. It's being deprecated.  AND the explorer prompted me to grant permissions which I need to eliminate in my scenario above.